# Android Gridview random duplicate items

Tags: android, gridview, android-gridview

i'm using `GridView`, and have issue with duplicating view's in grid, i'm getting images from Facebook api and then  asynchronously loading image to `ImageView`

**Update:**
For Asyncronus Image Loading source i'm getting from [BitmapFun](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) in Android Tutorials

**GalleryAdapter.java**

```
private class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

        private final Context mContext;
        private List<String> mPhotos = new ArrayList<String>();

        public ImageAdapter(Context context){
            super();
            mContext = context;
        }

        public void setPhotos(String... url){
            mPhotos = Arrays.asList(url);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        public void setPhotos(List<String> url){
            mPhotos = url;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mPhotos.size();
        }

        @Override
        public String getItem(int position) {
            return mPhotos.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return getItem(position).hashCode();
        }

        @Override
        public int getViewTypeCount() {
            return getCount() + 1;
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
            if(imageView == null){
                imageView = new RecyclingImageView(mContext);
                imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                imageView.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(150, 150));
            }

            mImageFetcher.loadImage(getItem(position), imageView);
            return imageView;
        }
    }
```

[image: duplicated image][image: duplicated image]

**Update:**
For Asyncronus Image Loading source i'm getting from [BitmapFun](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) in Android Tutorials

Comment: The URLs you are using in your Adapter, Are they unique for every photo? if this is the case, a simple string comparison will remove duplicates and do the job.

Comment: are u using Universal Image loader?

Comment: all url's which i getting is uniques

Comment: *Rashmi*, no i'm using loading from bitmap fun, source you can find in android bitmap displaying effectiv tutorials

Comment: what is mImageFetcher?? can you post the exact code for that as well. Also list view reuses view so this must be because of that. Use universal image loader to load image in a list view or handle such a case in your asynchronous bitmap loader functio

Comment: For Asyncronus Image Loading source i'm getting from BitmapFun in Android Tutorials

Answer (score 0):

Try catching of bitmaps as described [here](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html). By setting in memory cache will do your job.

Alternatively you can have  [Universal image loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) this will do catching for you. You just need to pass the url of image to the imageview

Comment: i'm learned in tutorial's and using it's image loader, and it's duplicates

Comment: Well you can have multiple options for image loading like Android Smart Image View http://loopj.com/android-smart-image-view/, square's picasso  https://github.com/square/picasso u can have a try